# Queue implementation with heap

Tags: c++, queue, heap-memory

I'm trying to implement a queue.

This is my framework

```
class Queue { 
 HANDLE heap;    
 Int *buf;     
 Int head, tail;   
 Int spaceAllocated;  
 Int sizeQ;    
public: 
 void Push (Int item);    
 Int Pop (Int *array, int batchSize);  
}
```

I'm doing this with a heap using windows API.
What is the purpose of the buffer and how is it used?  I know it has something to do with the heap and holding memory.

Comment: Consider this: Where would you store the objects that are Push'ed into the queue?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Windows API but you need a data structure for saving your data, right? If no buffer is used, where will you save them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Buf is the actual memory pointer you'll use to store your items.  I imagine you're using VirtualAlloc() here to create your buffer?  If so, you need to know the maximum size of your queue.

As an aside, why can you not use the STL queue?